# Enabling Image Buttons when Radio Buttons are clicked is not working in ASPX

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button, imagebutton

I am working on my first ASPX project using Visual Studio 2010. I have a page with Radio Button options of Female or Male. Under each is three Image Buttons. IF it was working the way I want it to, the three Image Buttons under Female Radio Button should be enabled, and the three Image Buttons under Male Radio Button should be disabled, and vice versa. It should also be able to change if the client decides Male instead of Female, and vice versa.

Here is how I'm programming the Radio Buttons:

```
protected void registerFemaleRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    imgbtnRegisterMale1.Enabled = false;
    imgbtnRegisterMale2.Enabled = false;
    imgbtnRegisterMale3.Enabled = false;`

    imgbtnRegisterFemale1.Enabled = true;
    imgbtnRegisterFemale2.Enabled = true;
    imgbtnRegisterFemale3.Enabled = true;
}

protected void registerMaleRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    imgbtnRegisterFemale1.Enabled = false;
    imgbtnRegisterFemale2.Enabled = false;
    imgbtnRegisterFemale3.Enabled = false;

    imgbtnRegisterMale1.Enabled = true;
    imgbtnRegisterMale2.Enabled = true;
    imgbtnRegisterMale3.Enabled = true;
}
```

When I debug, Image Buttons in the other Radio Button group are still enabled even after a Radio Button is clicked and when I switch Radio Buttons, some Image Buttons are permanently disabled and other that shouldn't be are enabled.

I have looked into putting the images in a Panel, which is supposed to work like a Group Box, changing the Attributes of the Image Buttons, and somehow refreshing the page after each Radio Button is selected. I did try to change the Attribute if the Image Buttons, but it had the same effect as the code above. What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @DavidStratton: I am creating a Web version of a C# program. I don't hav enough experience to rework all the coding, so I'm trying to keep with the C# counterpart.

Comment: Actually, I may have mis-read your original code.  Thanks to @Andre for formatting it..  At any rate, my entire answer is probably moot at this point.  Based on what's currently showing, my best bet is that somewhere else in the code, the buttons are being set to enabled.  I'd do a search for "imgbtnRegisterMale1.Enabled" in the code and see if it's being set somewhere else.

Comment: @David Stratton: In case someone else sees this, my buttons are not being enabled anywhere else. I checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the ASPX Page 
You Added the Property   AutoPostBack="true"

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="registerMaleRadioButton" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  />
```